# Python grouping similar patterns using regex

Tags: python, regex, string

I want to match `or` with the string I obtain and group the result based on the times `or` occurs.

My input will be like:

```
a or b*~c or 27*y or 5*~b
```

so my output should be:

```
a, b*~c, 27*y, 5*~b
```

My code works if there are exactly 3 `or`, but returns `[]` otherwise.

I am new to python and I don't understand exactly how the pattern must be given to the compile function.

```
import re
input = raw_input(" ")

ans = re.compile(r'(.*) or (.*) or (.*) or (.*)')
print re.findall(ans, input)
```

Comment: Simply split your string using `str.split('or')`. `re.split` is expected to be slower,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a simple `split` without any use of `re`.

```
input = raw_input()
ans = input.split("or")
```

or

```
ans = input.split(" or ")
```

If you want to use `findall` you can use

```
x="a or b*~c or 27*y or 5*~b"
print re.findall(r"(?:^|(?<=\bor\b))\s*(.*?)\s*(?=\bor\b|$)",x)
```

For both `*` and `or` use

```
x="a or b*~c or 27*y or 5*~b"
print [i.split("*") for i in x.split(" or ")]
```

Output:`[['a'], ['b', '~c'], ['27', 'y'], ['5', '~b']]`

Comment: And the deference is: First one returns `['foo ', ' bar']` and the second one returns `['foo', 'bar']` (says that the string is `foobar`).

Comment: @vks how can I split _both_ 'or' and '*'? Basically reducing them to list of lists. My answer should be `[[a], [b,~c], [27,y], [5,~b]]`   Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Just do splitting according to the sub-string `or`

```
re.split(r' or ', s)
```

or

```
re.split(r'\s+or\s+', s)
```